# Fluentd : Filter few events based on a condition

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I have a stream of events coming from container log files tagged as `kubernetes.*` , now out of these logs , I want to apply a custom filter to events of a certain container.

I was able to achieve this by adding a `rewrite_tag_filter` out plugin, but in result - the events which matched the TAG kubernetes.** but not the RULE itself are dropped after this match i.e they are not matched with next match.

Please help how all events can be propagated till last match directive ?

TIA

```
<source>
  ...
  ...
  tag kubernetes.*
</source>

<match kubernetes.**> // with this match , all events are matched here
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  hostname_command /bin/sh -c 'echo $HOSTNAME'
  <rule>
    key $.kubernetes.container_image
    pattern /.*container-x.*/
    tag k8s.json-parse
  </rule>
</match>

<filter k8s.json-parse>
  @type custom_plugin
  key_to_parse msg
</filter>

<match **> ## I want to have all the events which didn't follow the rule to be available here as well....not to be dropped in the above match...
...
...
</match>
```